# How does the constructor turn your compiled contract into a deployed contract?

Tags: solidity, compilation

The input is: you just compiled a contract

The output is: your contract is deployed

---

How did your constructor get from A to B? And how is the state storage reserved which is associated with your deployed contract.

Comment: I think your question is too broad, I means it is a good question but it is impossible to write in a single answer. There's a serie of articles with detailed analysis of how solidity is implemented to run in the EVM https://blog.qtum.org/diving-into-the-ethereum-vm-6e8d5d2f3c30

Comment: Reduced question scope to just the deploy step (the constructor)

Comment: The series pointed previously has a full chapter dedicated to [Diving Into The Ethereum VM Part 5 — The Smart Contract Creation Process](https://medium.com/@hayeah/diving-into-the-ethereum-vm-part-5-the-smart-contract-creation-process-cb7b6133b855)